# Numpy isnan() fails on an array of floats (from pandas dataframe apply)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have an array of floats (some normal numbers, some nans) that is coming out of an apply on a pandas dataframe.

For some reason, numpy.isnan is failing on this array, however as shown below, each element is a float, numpy.isnan runs correctly on each element, the type of the variable is definitely a numpy array.

What's going on?!

```
set([type(x) for x in tester])
Out[59]: {float}

tester
Out[60]: 
array([-0.7000000000000001, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
   nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
   nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
   nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
   nan, nan], dtype=object)

set([type(x) for x in tester])
Out[61]: {float}

np.isnan(tester)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-62-e3638605b43c>", line 1, in <module>
np.isnan(tester)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

set([np.isnan(x) for x in tester])
Out[65]: {False, True}

type(tester)
Out[66]: numpy.ndarray
```

Answer (score 207, accepted):

`np.isnan` can be applied to NumPy arrays of native dtype (such as np.float64):

```
In [99]: np.isnan(np.array([np.nan, 0], dtype=np.float64))
Out[99]: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

but raises TypeError when applied to object arrays:

```
In [96]: np.isnan(np.array([np.nan, 0], dtype=object))
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

---

Since you have Pandas, you could use [`pd.isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) instead -- it can accept NumPy arrays of object or native dtypes:

```
In [97]: pd.isnull(np.array([np.nan, 0], dtype=float))
Out[97]: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)

In [98]: pd.isnull(np.array([np.nan, 0], dtype=object))
Out[98]: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Note that `None` is also considered a null value in object arrays.

Comment: Thanks - used pd.isnull(). Does not appear to be any performance impact either.

Answer (score 14):

A great substitute for np.isnan() and pd.isnull() is

```
for i in range(0,a.shape[0]):
    if(a[i]!=a[i]):
       //do something here
       //a[i] is nan
```

since only nan is not equal to itself.

Comment: that may not work for arrays because it raises the well-known "ValueError: Truth value of a xxx is ambiguous".

Comment: @MSeifert Are you talking about **python**? I just use this method to do something in machine learning, Why I didn't encounter the well-known error?

Comment: Yes, seems like you haven't used numpy or pandas before. Just use `import numpy as np; a = np.array([1,2,3, np.nan])` and run your code.

Comment: @MSeifert er, I am new to numpy but the code ran ok, no error happed

Comment: In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a=np.array([1,2,3,np.nan])

In [3]: print a
[  1.   2.   3.  nan]

In [4]: print a[3]==a[3]
False

Comment: your code is about `a != a` not `a[3] == a[3]`. Please note that `a != a` will work(!) as long as you don't do `if a != a: pass`.

Comment: Should consider the original question.

Answer (score 10):

On top of @unutbu answer, you could coerce pandas numpy object array to native (float64) type, something along the line

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_numeric(df['tester'], errors='coerce')
```

Specify errors='coerce' to force strings that can't be parsed to a numeric value to become NaN. Column type would be `dtype: float64`, and then `isnan` check should work

Comment: His name seems to be `unutbu` ;)

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure you import csv file using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

condition = pd.isnull(data[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just answer this for a reminder of myself. It took me a whole day to solve.
After digging deep into the code, I found that in `_encodepy.py`:

```
if values.dtype.kind in 'UO':
    # correct branch
else
    # wrong branch, if in this branch whatever data you give it will produce the error
    if np.isnan(known_values).any(): # here is problematic line
```

so the solution is very simple, just `astype` your data with `np.object`