# Isnan is not supported for the input types Python Imputer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Import Data set

dataset= pd.read_csv('Data.csv') 
X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[:,3].values

#Taking Care of The Missing Data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputer = Imputer(missing_values='nan',strategy='mean',axis=0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:,1:3])

X[:,1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:,1:3])
```

I was following this tutorial series and did exactly as he tutor did with me of course having this error as mentioned in the code. A potential solution would be of course very helpful. Thanks in advance.

> ```
> Error : if value_to_mask == "NaN" or np.isnan(value_to_mask):
> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the
> inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to
> the casting rule ''safe''
> ```

Comment: Error :  if value_to_mask == "NaN" or np.isnan(value_to_mask):

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: which line results in that error

Comment: @Primusa the Imputer = Imputer(Missing Values...) one.

Comment: Won't work on string values, likely. Convert it first `X[:,1:3].astype(str)` and try it again

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've been using integers and not strings. Same error.

Comment: You may want to try `missing_values='NaN'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try :

```
imputer = Imputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean',axis=0)
```

or

```
imputer = Imputer(missing_values='NaN',strategy="mean",axis=0)
```

as mentioned in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html)

Comment: The first one works, the second one doesnt, Any idea why?

Comment: @DawoodZaidi For more details you use this as a supportive answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000993/numpy-isnan-fails-on-an-array-of-floats-from-pandas-dataframe-apply