# python seaborn heat map

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to recreate the following heatmap from with my own dataset from the following:

https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/heatmap_annotation.html

I'm getting the following error:

calc_data = plot_data.data[~np.isnan(plot_data.data)]
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, a

Any help getting it resolved would be greatly appreciated.  The data seems to load and pivot properly but maybe not in the correct dtype.

Thanks,

Tim

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set()

# Load the example flights dataset and convert to long-form

flights_long = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

flights = flights_long.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")


# Draw a heatmap with the numeric values in each cell

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d", linewidths=.5, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000993/numpy-isnan-fails-on-an-array-of-floats-from-pandas-dataframe-apply

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy isnan() fails on an array of floats (from pandas dataframe apply)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000993/numpy-isnan-fails-on-an-array-of-floats-from-pandas-dataframe-apply)

Comment: Possible duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000993/numpy-isnan-fails-on-an-array-of-floats-from-pandas-dataframe-apply