# Convert NaN values in numpy array to mean of values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array called heart_rate of shape (1181,) and dtype float.
In my data there is occasionally the word None.
I would like to get rid of this and replace it with the average of the data values. 
When I try and run the following code:

```
inds = np.where(np.isnan(heart_rate))
```

But I am getting TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: we need more information. what is the shape of heart_rate? what is its dtype?

Comment: This should solve your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000993/numpy-isnan-fails-on-an-array-of-floats-from-pandas-dataframe-apply

Comment: the simplest way is actually use the fillna method with mean method.....like this.... inds.fillna(inds.mean())