# Plotting 3D surface with matplotlib with 3 columns of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, surface

I know usually we use:

```
plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

where `X`, `Y` are 1-D array and `Z` a matrix of dimension `len(X)` × `len(Y)`, to plot a surface.

But I now have only three columns of 1-D array as data. In other words, I have something like:

```
X=[1,2,3,4,5]
Y=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

and

```
Z=f(X,Y)=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I do not have the expression of `f`, but I want to plot a surface diagram nevertheless. How should I do it?

Please feel free to ask me to clarify my question. This is my first time asking questions on the platform.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you mean?:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
z=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,cmap='viridis')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However when use pandas to read my csv data in an error occurs at ``ax.plot_surace(x, y, z, camp='viridis')``. The error is "TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types". Do you happen to have any idea to resolve this?

Comment: @YunhanSheng - I've found such an answer:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32981/how-to-deal-with-typeerror-ufunc-isnan-not-supported-for-the-input-types

and the second one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000993/numpy-isnan-fails-on-an-array-of-floats-from-pandas-dataframe-apply

Comment: Thank you ktp, this does work. Now I'm trying to read and import my own data to see if I need to adjust some details. Thanks!